# Lakes and Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Imagine a lake which is polluted and can only be cleaned by natural process of gradually replacing the water in the lake. The following assumptions are made:

1. Volume is constant
   2.Pollutants are uniformaly distributed in the water
   3.Pollutants are only removed by the water flowing out of the lake
   4.No pollutants are retained in the lake-they all flow out freely

Definition of variables: V (volume of lake in hectolitres)
PL(pollution at any time in kg per hectolitere), Pi (pollution concentration inflow in kg hectolitre), r(rate of flow), t(time in years).

Formulate a Differential Equation which represents the rate at which PL (pollution at any time) is changing

Answer (score 0):

The amount of pollution at time $t$ is $PL(t)$. You want an equation for the rate at which PL is changing, so you want an equation for the derivative of $PL(t)$.

Now, pollution is flowing into the lake (at, say, rate $A$), and it is also leaving the lake as water flows out of the lake (at, say, rate $B$). How would you relate the rate at which PL is changing to $A$ and $B$?

Now, if you know the concentration of pollution in what's coming into the lake, and you know the rate of flow of water into the lake, you should be able to work out $A$, the rate of flow of pollution into the lake.

And if you know the concentration of pollution in the lake, and the rate of flow of water out of the lake, you should be able to work out $B$.

Putting it all together, you should get the equation you're after.

Be sure to let your instructor know if you use any of this to get your equation.

EDIT: The assignment is probably past due now, so let's clean this one up.

The rate at which pollution flows in is the rate of flow times the concentration of pollution in the inflow: $r\times Pi$.

The rate at which pollution flows out is the rate of flow times the concentration of pollution in the lake: $r\times PL\div V$.

The net rate of change of the amount of pollution is the difference between these two: $r\times PI-(r\times PL)/V$.

So the equation we want is $${d\,PL\over dt}=r\times Pi-{r\times PL\over V}$$